# Apache Nifi: ExecuteSql processor issue with where clause SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, apache-nifi, hortonworks-dataflow

I am using Apache Nifi 1.3.0, I am using ExecuteSql processor for reading records from MS SQL `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP:1433/DBNAME` database.

The issue is I am able to retrieve records from MS SQL using ExecuteSql processor only if my SQL statement is without where clause, e.g. `select * from Table` but when I use SQL statement like `select * from Table where ID > 10` ExecuteSql processor fails to get results, all I get is empty Avro schema records.

```
Objavro.schema▒{"type":"record","name":"NiFi_ExecuteSQL_Record","namespace":"any.data","fields":[{"name":"ID","type":["null","int"]},{"name":"COL1","type":["null","long"]},{"name":"COL2","type":["null","int"]},{"name":"COL3","type":["null","int"]},{"name":"COL4","type":["null","int"]}]}G▒▒@▒[ж▒6
```

Comment: so maybe there is no records with `ID > 10` in your database? because `ExecuteSql` just sends the request to the sql server.

Comment: @ daggett, it has records, it also works with '=' but not with '>' or '<' quite strange..

Comment: 1) check that you are connecting to right server/database `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS [MachineName], SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS [ServerName], db_name() as [DB]` 2) try repeat error by selecting from system table like `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` with `<` or `>`